# Refresh component on back-key

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have written a react component composed of two child components. All three are functional components which utilize hooks.

Think of a visit to Amazon searching for a video card. On the left are filters you might use: resolution, type of connection, number of connections, etc. As you choose filter values the component to the right displays applicable thumbnails for those items matching your selected criteria.

When clicking on one of the thumbnails, the parent and children (filter and thumbnails) windows are replaced with a detail component. The original window is not visible. Hitting the back key, the original components, including the selected filters and thumbnails, should be as before.

However, when hitting the back-key, the original component with its children displays without any of the selected filters.

I am using react v16.11.0 and react-router-dom v5.1.2.

Clearly I am lost. Can anyone suggest an approach?

Comment: Hi. Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where your bug appears so people can replicate it and try to solve it

Comment: It is full of calls to SQL. I am trying to remove all of the backend to make a mwe.

Comment: +Sandbox: (https://pkq7g.csb.app/prodCat)  
    +Select link 'Product Category' on right  
    +Click on drop-down option 'An Item'  
    +This is the page I wish to navigate back to  
    +Click on any of the 3 items  
    +Then click the back key  
    +You are taken to /prodCat, not /catgDispatch/84  
    where user can select another thumbnail based on search criteria
    -How do I get back to that route?

Answer (score 0):

I used  rather than . The router was not recording the transition in history. I was already at the route to which I wished to navigate **before** hitting the back-key.